# create and save csv file without any third party library in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have all the data fetched from backend and I need to save all the data as CSV on button click in reactJS app. So far  solutions in js include appending an object and mock clicking on it. I do not need any third party library such as CSVLink because it requires a format that I think is unnecessary for my need and I will use nested objects and I am willing make complex code. So I'm stuck in this saving part mainly. I thought using axios and `URL.createObjectURL` on a blob object but that seems not a good idea.
How can I do it?

My try code:

```
...
const testCSV = "H1, H2, H3, Hydrogen, Oxygen, Water"; //save it as .csv file

const data = [
    { firstname: "Ahmed", lastname: "Tomi", email: "ah@smthing.co.com" },
    { firstname: "Raed", lastname: "Labes", email: "rl@smthing.co.com" },
    { firstname: "Yezzi", lastname: "Min l3b", x: "ymin@cocococo.com" },
];
    
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)]);
const ahref = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

function TESTFunc() {
    console.log("Hello");
}
return (
    <Container fluid >
        
        {/* I do not want this
        <Button variant="secondary">
        <CSVLink data={data} headers={headers}>
            Download me
        </CSVLink>
        </Button>
        */}

        <Button variant="success" onClick={TESTFunc}></Button> {//download on this button click}
    </Container>
);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const downloadCSV = (csv, filename) => {
  const blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv' });

  if (navigator && navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    const dataURI = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${csv}`;

    const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    const downloadURI =
      typeof URL.createObjectURL === 'undefined' ? dataURI : URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', downloadURI);
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }
};
```